# Iterate over every possible n-sampling of a list

Tags: python, python-itertools, combinatorics

If I understand [`itertools` "combinatoric iterators"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) doc correctly, the idea is to provide a set of standard functions for every common combinatory iteration.

But I miss one today. I need to iterate over every *ordered* combinations of items with repetitions.

`combination_with_replacement('abcd', 4)` yields

```
('a', 'a', 'a', 'a')
('a', 'a', 'a', 'b')
('a', 'a', 'a', 'c')
('a', 'a', 'a', 'd')
('a', 'a', 'b', 'b')
('a', 'a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'a', 'b', 'd')
('a', 'a', 'c', 'c')
('a', 'a', 'c', 'd')
... etc
```

but (even though the results are sorted tuples), these combinations are not *ordered*.

I expect more results from an ideal `ordered_combination_with_replacement('abcd', 4)` for I need to distinguish between

```
('a', 'a', 'a', 'a')
('a', 'a', 'a', 'b')
('a', 'a', 'b', 'a')
('a', 'b', 'a', 'a')
('b', 'a', 'a', 'a')
('a', 'a', 'a', 'c')
('a', 'a', 'c', 'a')
... etc
```

In other words: order matters today.

Does itertool provide such an iteration? Why not, or why have I missed it?
What's a standard way to iterate over those?
Do I need to write this generic iterator myself?

Comment: Are you looking for `product('abcd', repeat=4)`?

Comment: I mean, to my eyes it looks like the combination with replacement gave a perfectly reasonable order, Just not the one you wanted?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am. I missed the `repeat` argument :) Cheers!

Comment: @ParitoshSingh It gave only one order for each combination where I wanted *every possible* order for each combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wrap up some of the comments, there are (at least) two ways to do that:

```
itertools.combinations_with_replacement("abcd", 4)
```

and

```
itertools.product("abcd", repeat=4)
```

Both produce the required results of:

```
[('a', 'a', 'a', 'a'),
 ('a', 'a', 'a', 'b'),
 ('a', 'a', 'a', 'c'),
 ('a', 'a', 'a', 'd'),
 ('a', 'a', 'b', 'a'),
 ...
```